# What are your favourite ZX Spectrum development tools?

Tags: z80, sinclair, zxspectrum

What are your favourite assemblers, compilers, environments, interpreters for the 
good old [ZX Spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX_Spectrum)?

Comment: People who are down voting are probably unaware that there are cross compiler environments for retro computers. To the uninitiated, this means there are Windows/Linux/Mac IDE's for programming for older systems. People are still making software for these older systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always used to use [Roybot Assembler](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/infoseek.cgi?regexp=%5EComplete+Machine+Code+Package$&pub=%5ERoybot$&loadpics=1) - which had you enter your program using the BASIC editor and REM statements.  It comes with a decent debugger/disassembler that lets you single-step machine code too.

The Hisoft Gens and Mons assembler and disassembler (aka Devpak) are probably fairly popular.

For high-level compiling, the [Mira Modula-2](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/infoseekid.cgi?id=0012459) compiler is very good.

Answer (score 5):

Hisoft Gens and Mons assembler and disassembler for programming/debugging.

The Artist / The Art Studio for graphics:
http://www.worldofspectrum.org/infoseekid.cgi?id=0007918

The Music Box for sound:
http://www.worldofspectrum.org/infoseekid.cgi?id=0008481

Answer (score 4):

[Zeus assembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeus_Assembler), was the best.

I'd add a couple of the Spectrum books in there if I could remember the names, still have them at home. One was The Complete Spectrum ROM Disassembly by Ian Logan and Frank O'Hara (ISBN 0 86161 116 0), which was commented and described as if it was the source, a fantastic piece of reverse engineering, including a suggested bug fix for the known ROM bugs. If only flash memory had been around in those days. I also memorised a tiny book called the Z80 Workshop Manual which was a great summary of the processor.

Comment: Z80 Workshop Manual is fantastic. Easy to read and still packed with useful informaiton.

Answer (score 3):

Just programming in BASIC, the commands are right there on those rubbery keys. Now if only PC's could have key-legends with while, case, switch etc. on them :-)

Answer (score 3):

**ZX ASM 3.0**

It had the best user interface and good feature set compared to other assemblers at the end of the twentieth century.

Answer (score 2):

I used to type in hex-tables from a magazine and then a a short basic application to unpack the data into assembly code. I couldn't make heads nor tails of it for ages until I discovered I wasn't actually coding at all!

I then moved onto [Z80 assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilog_Z80#The_Z80_assembly_language) on a College owned [CP/M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) mini computer system.  Programming the Speccy was never the same after that and I never went back!

Answer (score 2):

Devpac (a blue cassette) comes to my mind, even after all these years.

Sure, it was #1. I don't miss the cassette loadings, though.  Nice question!!!  :D

http://www.clive.nl/detail/22916/

I think I had v.3.  It sure looked much more home-made than the this pic. But it *worked* and didn't have a single bug. Beat that, current software!!!

Answer (score 2):

For contemporary development, [TommyGun](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tommygun/) is an excellent choice.

It has a built in assembler, map editor, graphics editor and other goodies. It also supports multiple 8-bit platforms.

It works well in conjunction with the excellent [ZX Spin](http://worldofspectrum.org/forums/showthread.php?t=27547) emulator for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

BASin, TommyGun, ConTEXT and the Pasmo cross-compiler.  Works great with the ZXSpin emulator too,,

Answer (score 1):

ZX-Asm v3.1 + patched HiSoft-C v1.1 / figFORTH / BetaBasic 3.0

Answer (score 1):

There are some good PC-based packages too. For Sinclair BASIC based development the excellent BASin package for Windows gives you a good syntax highlighter, runtime virtual machine, built-in editors for fonts and UDG's etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assembler Prometheus from Proxima Software.

Comment: yep I used it too a lot :) even the Disc D40/D80 version and plus DEVASTACE  onscreen disassembler

Answer (score 0):

Well outside of GEN80, [HiSoft Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HiSoft_Systems) and [Hisoft C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HiSoft_Systems) were pretty impressive.  *Proper* high level languages, way cool.  Before I learnt Z80, and was frustrated by the speed of BASIC, I also loved [MCODER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX_Spectrum_software), though more on the ZX81 than ZX Spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Z88DK, but I think also SDCC may be of interest.